# How to assign XY and ID to be read in adehabitatRS

Tags: r-sp

I´ve been trying to run adehabitat but after my species/presence- coordinates are transformed XY components go missing.

## CSV file with species/presence- coordinates

```
> registros <- read.csv("~/Desktop/datos habitat.csv")
> head(registros,3)
         Especie         X       Y
1        C.thous -71.42153 5.98031
2 H.hydrochaeris -71.42153 5.98031
3     L.pardalis -71.42153 5.98031
```

## Coordinate projection form lat-long

```
> coordinates(registros) <-c("X","Y")
> proj4string(registros) <- CRS("+init=epsg:4326")
> registros <- spTransform(registros, CRS("+init=epsg:21898"))
```

## XY coordinates gone missing, only species variable if left.

```
> head(registros)
         Especie
1        C.thous
2 H.hydrochaeris
3     L.pardalis
4   M.tridactyla
5  O.virginianus
6     P.concolor
```

## So when I try to create a list to run adehabitat only sp. variable is present on the locs set.

```
$map
class       : SpatialPixelsDataFrame 
dimensions  : 2614, 3084, 8061576, 2  (nrow, ncol, npixels, nlayers)
resolution  : 9.259e-05, 9.259e-05  (x, y)
extent      : -71.59446, -71.30891, 5.876562, 6.118592  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +init=epsg:21898 +proj=tmerc +lat_0=4.599047222222222 +lon_0=-71.08091666666667 +k=1 +x_0=1000000 +y_0=1000000 +ellps=intl +towgs84=307,304,-318,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
names       :            v_eco.agua, v_eco.bosque 
min values  : -2.60905458751601e-05,            0 
max values  :    0.0236267629555045,          376 

$relocs
class       : SpatialPointsDataFrame 
features    : 270 
extent      : 949058.7, 966743.8, 1147074, 1165429  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
coord. ref. : +init=epsg:21898 +proj=tmerc +lat_0=4.599047222222222 +lon_0=-71.08091666666667 +k=1 +x_0=1000000 +y_0=1000000 +ellps=intl +towgs84=307,304,-318,0,0,0,0 +units=m +no_defs 
variables   : 1
names       :        Especie 
min values  :         C.paca 
max values  : T.tetradactyla
```

Any suggestions in how can I solve this problem?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

They are not gone, it is only because the `head` method used comes frmo `raster` and does not print them. If your R session loads `sp` but does load `raster`, the `head` command (from `sp`) will show your coordinates.